# File Load Exception Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've run this app on 3 different servers, and on the final prod server, I cannot get it to work correctly. Its a WebAPI 2.0 App, the servers all have the same .NET Framework installed..

The Full Error is: **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.**

Where does it need permission? I have verified it has the same permissions as the other 3 servers it ran successfully on. It will not show me a detailed error report, only in the Event Viewer can i see the error it is throwing.

Does this mean its a .NET version issue because it can't even get to a point where it can output the error to me? It just says my webconfig is configured incorrectly to display the error, which it is not. I have customErrors set to Off.

I can not find any other thread or page where people have had issues with this assembly, so i'm hoping someone else has had this issue before.

Thank you.

Comment: If your production does not have direct Internet access, ask the developers of this web application to remove Roslyn NuGet package from their solution.

Comment: That worked..the question is why? Every app has that package that is deployed. Why is it throwing a fit now?

Comment: I don't know the exact cause yet. You might prepare a test server, block direct Internet access to simulate and then do further debugging.

Comment: Weird thing is, this app has been on the dev and test server and worked just fine. Oh well, I guess it works now so thank you.

Comment: This happened for me with the default Web Application template in VS2015. Removing the <compilers> and <httpModules> in the web.config worked.

Comment: @bump Your solution worked for me as well. Thank you.